# Increase the average depth for the MInimax algorithm in Chess?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, p5.js, chess, minimax

I recently built a chess engine in p5.js using the Minimax Algorithm with alpha beta pruning but the maximum ply depth that I am able to achieve is 4, increasing it to 5 consumes almost 10 seconds for a move, so can someone suggest some method of increasing the ply depth and reducing the search time. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I recently build a chess engine as well and was able to get it to a depth of 5 and even 6. However, I built mine in Python, but I think there is some general advice I can give that may be applicable to your project.

1. *Edit your code to shave microseconds off the functions that check the state of the board, and that get all the valid moves.*

These microseconds add up to a significant amount of time when you analyse millions of positions! I remember spending a couple of evenings trying make my code as fast as it possible could be. In the end it shaved a few seconds off the runtime at depth 5.

2. *Analyse the center of the board before analysing the edges.*

The strength of the alpha-beta pruning is that it won't investigate obviously worse moves. So it is imperative that you find the best move as quickly as possible. Rather than checking the moves on the sides first, tell the algorithm to start in the middle (Column D or E) and work its way outwards. These moves are typically the best, and hence the algorithm will prune more branches.

3. *Reduce the complexity of checking the state of the board*

With each engine there is a trade off between speed and accuracy. Take a look the this heuristic to analysing the position of board: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Simplified_Evaluation_Function. Defining positional advantage like this is a fast way to get a half-decent engine. Though it tends to break down in the mid/end game.

Hope this helps, and good luck!